# Create view with parent taxonomy terms only

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view of nodes, which are associated with a vocabulary, and it contains both child and their respective parent terms. What I want is in this view, only the parent categories will be coming. I have already tried the parent relationship but it gives me repetitive rows with each parents. I have described the problem and what i want to achieve here :

https://www.drupal.org/node/652234#comment-9422885

Help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Create contextual filter with parent taxonomy term id as fixed value 0

Answer (score 0):

In views add filter:

Taxonomy term: Parent term and it is equal to NULL, leave blank.